# How to Emulate Android Market App?

Tags: android

I have developed 3 android applications and hosted in my own site.

Can someone please help me in the following questions I have:

A. With my own Client
       1. How to do Silent Installations?
       2. How to do Multiple Installations from a URL(User Checks multiple applications from the site and clicks on Download button. And it download applications one by one)?
       3. How can I get the information on the uninstalled myown apps from the user mobile. Or how can I check whether one application is installed there or not?

B. Can I Leverage Google's Client services in the Andorid OS to do the above things (Avoiding to create my own client)

Comment: I don't know if you can replicate the silent install and I honestly hope that it is impossible.

Comment: @Haphazard There are permissions that allow this, but they can only be used by applications at the system level (like Market).

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please take a look at it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom build of android with your own *original* system-certificate application market/installer which talks to your servers rather than Google's.

Otherwise you are talking about spoofing Google's credentials, which is a topic for security research, not development.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please take a look at it again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My answer is unchanged - this is not functionality which is offered to third parties.  If you must have this, you need to develop a custom android build signed with your certificate, and containing your own original installer application which gives you, rather than Google, this power.  Otherwise you must go through the user approval dialog or install from a connected computer over ADB, just like everyone else.